# Pythonic way to load image resources

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I have a file called `resources.py` which loads images to be used in the main project.

**So far the code looks like this:**

```py
import pyglet
pyglet.resource.path = ["../resources", "C:/users/____/Pictures/useful icons"]
pyglet.resource.reindex()
checkbox_unchecked = pyglet.resource.image("checkbox_unchecked.png")
checkbox_checked = pyglet.resource.image("checkbox_checked.png")
checkbox_unchecked_dark = pyglet.resource.image("checkbox_unchecked_dark.png")
checkbox_checked_dark = pyglet.resource.image("checkbox_checked_dark.png")
checkbox_unchecked_thick = pyglet.resource.image("checkbox_unchecked_thick.png")
checkbox_checked_thick = pyglet.resource.image("checkbox_checked_thick.png")
checkbox_unchecked_disabled = pyglet.resource.image("checkbox_unchecked_disabled.png")
checkbox_checked_disabled = pyglet.resource.image("checkbox_checked_disabled.png")
```

---

I thought that this is an unwieldy way to do it, so what came to my mind is something like:

```py
import pyglet
pyglet.resource.path = ['../resources', "C:/users/____/Pictures/useful icons"]
pyglet.resource.reindex()
images = ["checkbox_unchecked.png", "checkbox_checked.png", ...]
for image in images:
    exec(f'{image} = pyglet.resource.image("{image}")')
```

---

This of course uses the exec function which I know is frowned upon as there is usually a better way of doing it. The only other way I can see of doing it is creating a dictionary instead.

**Like so:**

```py
import pyglet
pyglet.resource.path = ['../resources', "C:/users/____/Pictures/useful icons"]
pyglet.resource.reindex()
images = ["checkbox_unchecked.png", "checkbox_checked.png", ...]
imageDict = {}
for image in images:
    imageDict[image] = pyglet.resource.image(image)
```

> Which of these (or other methods) is the most DRY-complient and
>   comprehensible way to load the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider a dictionary comprehension in combination with the `pathlib` module so that when you call keys from the dictionary you don't have to call them with the extension

```
from pathlib import Path
import pyglet
pyglet.resource.path = ['../resources', "C:/users/____/Pictures/useful icons"]
pyglet.resource.reindex()
images = ["checkbox_unchecked.png", "checkbox_checked.png", ...]
imageDict = { Path(image).stem: pyglet.resource.image(image) for image in images }
```

Then you would get your images out with:

```
imageDict['checkbox_unchecked']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your dictionary solution to get what you originally wanted by using `globals()`, which is a dict of all the global variables.

```
for image in images:
    globals()[image.split('.')[0]] = pyglet.resource.image(image)
```

Or:

```
globals().update((image.split('.')[0], pyglet.resource.image(image)) for image in images)
```